# CakePHP 3 Unknown email configuration "gmail" in cPanel server

Tags: cakephp

Email are sent successfully in local. But the problem occurs in production server that shows an error: unknown gmail configuration.

My email configuration looks like:

```
'gmail' => [

      'className' => 'Smtp',

      // The following keys are used in SMTP transports

      'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',

      'port' => 465,

      'timeout' => 60,

      'username' => 'noreplayxxxxx@gmail.com',

      'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

      'client' => null,

      'tls' => true,

  ]
```

What is the problem and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: May be you didn't upload appropriate app.php files in the server

Answer (score 0):

Make sure app.php file on your production server contains required configuration. app.php is ignored by git by default, so it might not get deployed in your case as you are expecting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use these in your controller

```
///////////////////// Configuration /////////////////////////

$host     = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$username = 'abc@gmail.com';
$password = 'xxxxxxx';
$port     = '465';
$email_to = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$senderName = 'abc';
$email_id_reply ='abc@gmail.com';

$new_attachments = '<some image>';
$msgsend ='Hello!!';

Email::configTransport('WebMail'.$recipient, 
                      [
                        'className' => 'Smtp',
                        'host' => $host,
                        'port' => $port,
                        'timeout' => 30,
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password,
                        'client' => null,
                        'tls' => null
                      ]
                    );

////////// SEND MAIL 

$transport = ['transport' => 'WebMail'.$recipient];

$email = new Email($transport);

$email  ->template('default','default')
      ->emailFormat('both')
      ->from([$username => $senderName])
      ->to($email_to)
      ->replyTo($email_id_reply)
      ->subject('Client Message');

$email->attachments($new_attachments);  

$response = $email->send($msgsend);
```